# Through xPath function, export informations about Artist and Title song from website

Tags: javascript, php, xpath, echo

I wanted to ask,

There is an online radio site by the name mytuner-radio. I was trying to pull out the information of what song is currently being played under "playing now" through Xpath, because there is no xml or json file with that information.

I am shareing my code with you, because I must be making a mistake in a step because im not getting the information, so I decided to ask for help and maybe this problem of mine can be an asset for the same purpose.

```html
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('https://mytuner-radio.com/pt/radio/radio-meo-music-414443/'));

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@class="history-song"]/spam[@class="song-name"][0] // spam[@class="song-artist"][0]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent . "\n";
} 
?>
```

I'm going to inspect element to try to get the information, through the DIV. I leave a print where the information is with the details underlined

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUpnL.png)

I'm going to inspect element to try to get the information, through the DIV. I leave a print where the information is, with the details underlined. In this case, I wanted to export the information contained in the "song-name" and "artist-name" spam class.

Comment: Well, perhaps, like many web sites today, perhaps the site relies on JavaScript to load/display most of its contents and that information you see in the browser is just not part of the static HTML you load with PHP?

Comment: @MartinHonnen As I don't have access to this information through Javascript, I thought of this way to get the information I want. I put it in php because I thought it was the best option. Not the most reliable solution?

Comment: First, posting images of code is a bad practice here. Second, your XPath should say `span` but it says `spam`